# How to return Thai Characters from SQLSRV to PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have this data from Sql Server that contains ID , Name and HEX of the Name

[image]

When i tried to view this table to PHP using sqlsrv_query

[image]

I need those names to return as Thai Characters from database

Comment: This doesn't really look like a problem with SQL Server, rather a problem with how you're displaying the values, not the way you're storing them. I suggest you also tag what version of PHP you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, i just added UTF-8 during connection to the sql server